# arraylist doesn't let enter only one host name to ping in powershell

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have a ping-script, which has the following input parameters

```
  param(
#Arralist zum Aufnehmen der Hosts.
#[parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][System.Collections.ArrayList]$Hosts = @(),
[parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][System.String]$Hosts,
#Anzahl Wiederholung pro Host, Standard 10 Jahre
[parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 1)][double]$Repetition = 315360000,
#solange wird nichts unternommen, standard 0
[parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 1)][double]$Pause = 5,
#Speicherort des Logfile, standard C:\Temp
[parameter(Mandatory = $false,Position = 2)][string]$LogPath = 'C:\Temp\Ping Tool'
)
```

if I invoke the script by using the script name and the needed parameters, like script.ps1 -hosts www.google.ch, www.youtube.com -repetition 2 the script will ping the two hosts 2 times and then stops. That is good so. But the problem occurs, if I have only one host(exam. www.google.ch) to ping. It says that `The argument transformation for the parameter "Hosts" can't be processed. The value "www.google.ch" of type "System.String" can't be converted to the type "System.Collections.ArrayList".`

What can I do, so that the script works even if I ping only one host? The problem here is that I defined an Arraylist in the parameters that is why it is not letting me enter only one host to ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the cast of `ArrayList` or `System.String` for the `$Hosts` parameter, and use `foreach` in your code to iterate each item, it will handle it alone...

See example:

```
function Test-Input {
param(
$hosts
)
Write-Host The Input is: [ $hosts.GetType().FullName ]

    foreach ($item in $hosts) {
    Write-Host Item: [ $item ]
    }
}
```

See the Results:

```
PS > Test-Input -hosts www.google.ch
The Input is: [ System.String ]
Item: [ www.google.ch ]

PS > Test-Input -hosts www.google.ch,www.google.com
The Input is: [ System.Object[] ]
Item: [ www.google.ch ]
Item: [ www.google.com ]
```

Comment: thx man. It works. Could you maybe explain me, why it didn't work before? difference between [ArrayList], [system.string] and a param without all of them like you said??

Comment: when you force a type for parameter, it validate it and not accepting other types, it's by design